login freeze after patch application
Ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64 working well since a year ore more, on Lenovo T410s.
Memory test done, 100% error free.
I accepted the last patch offer 2 days ago. Crash during automatic cleanup of previous version. It was a kernel patch if I remember correctly.
In 9 of 10 cases the login screen freezes, and access through ssh doesn't work either. Network apparently out of service. No response to ping request.
No keyboard or mouse reaction, hence only the power off button works to kill the OS.
Login to console doesn't work either.
But sometimes it is possible to login, and it is possible to open the terminal program for instance. In those moments it is possible to access via ssh too.
But suddenly gnome freeze again, and the network is killed also.
I was looking for a repair possibility on the USB-stick menu, but there is none.
How to repair, keeping my data save on the Laptop?

Luckily I could connect via ssh long enough to change grub to get access to the grub menu on the next boot.
Then I could select the 6.5 kernel and login normally. With “apt-get purge 6.8...kernel” I deleted the faulty 6.8.0-40 kernel. Now my Laptop works as it did before. Just perfect.
What I still don't know is what will happen, when the 6.8.0-40 kernel is offered again as patch update. Is the kernel faulty, or did just something go wrong during the patch installation. Hopefully the next version works as it should.
